# Any way to change a value on ODD/EVEN records in a sql Select statement?

Tags: sql-server

I just want to put in some false SQL Server 2008 database data to test the reports/charts in my app.

Is there any way to do this based on an internal count and find out if the current record is odd (1,3,5,7, etc.)?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table 
(CASE WHEN @recordsetID isODD THEN IsAdmin = 1 ELSE IsAdmin = 0 END) 
WHERE PassChange < GETDATE() -65;
```

`The @recordsetID isODD` value I am just making up to try and show what I mean. There is no AUTO-ID column in this particular Table.

|Thanks|

Comment: SQL tables have no inherent order. Therefore there is no concept of "odd" or "even" rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulus operation will do that... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @recordsetID % 2 = 0 THEN 'Even' ELSE 'Odd' END
```

So if a number divided by 2 has no remainder (@recordsetID % 2 = 0) it is even.

Comment: An autoID column is required, so I have added one.